# English tense reporting tool online

Tags: discussion, american-english, online-resources

Is there any online tool available that just reports the tense of the English sentence. I'm just checking the scope of the project.I've seen lot of online tool that they are correcting and rewriting but not reporting any details about the tenses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, any part-of-speech tagger includes tags like

- VBZ: Verb, 3rd person singular present
- VBD:  Verb, past tense

Those are [Penn tags](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html), which while limited are quite widely used. Any of the many online parsers will show you those, or you can download some NLP kit to build your own.

For example, [the Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/) uses them in parsing

> My dog also likes eating sausage.

as

```
My/PRP  dog/NN  also/RB  likes/VBZ  eating/VBG  sausage/NN  ./.
```

Each word is tagged with its part of speech using a Penn tag. The verb *likes* is tagged with VBZ because it's a 3rd-person singular present-tense verb. That page shows you that the full parse is

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP$ My) (NN dog))
    (ADVP (RB also))
    (VP (VBZ likes)
      (S
        (VP (VBG eating)
          (NP (NN sausage)))))
    (. .)))
```

## Past Tense, or Not?

Mind you that of course **sentences** don't have tense. Only finite **verbs** do, and your choices are just one of two possibilities: the only English tenses are past (a.k.a. preterite) and non-past (a.k.a. present).

And modal verbs don't have tense at all.